Prisma Migration Issue: "Migration history doesn't match" Error on Production Database
I'm encountering an issue with Prisma migrations in my NestJS application. My backend setup includes Prisma and PostgreSQL, and I'm using a remote database for my production environment. Every time I try to migrate any database schema changes on the production server, I get the following error:
Error: Migration history doesn't match
It suggests resetting the whole database, which unfortunately clears all the data in my production database. Here is a summary of my current workflow:

Backup Production Database: I take a backup of the production database before making any schema changes.
Migrate Schema Changes: I run the migration commands, which leads to the above error and ends up clearing the data.
Restore Data:I manually import the data back into the production database.

Steps I've Taken to Resolve the Issue:

Shadow Database Configuration: I've specified a different shadow database in my schema.prisma file:

datasource db {
  provider          = "postgresql"
  url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
}


Synchronize Migration History:
I've tried to ensure that the migration history in my local environment matches the one in production by copying migration files from production to local.

Deploying Migrations:
I've attempted to use the npx prisma migrate deploy command to apply the migrations without resetting the database, but the issue persists.


